# vueJS- prop is being mutated when local copy updates

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My child component template has two input elements with v-models as below.

```
<input v-model="user.name" />
<input v-model="user.email" />

props: {
   'account': {}
},
data: function() {
   return { user : this.account.user }
}
```

When ever the text in the input fields changes, The user object is being updated which is expected. But the prop `account.user` is also updating with the changes. How can i make it to update just the `user` object and keep the prop `account.user` as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because in Javascript, object is passed by reference. When you do `user : this.account.user`, you are passing the object reference to `user` data. That's why when you edit `user` data, `account.user` gets edited as well, they refer to the same object.

You can clone it using ES6 spread operator.

```
return { user : {...this.account.user} }
```

If you are not using ES6, i would suggest you to use [lodash clone](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#clone) instead.

```
return { user : _.clone(this.account.user) }
```

(Btw, the cloning methods above only works for shallow object. For deeply nested object, use lodash cloneDeep instead.)

Comment: Thanks. cloneDeep did the job.